# How can I insert the EventsTab in the PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, collections

Here is the deal, I have some collections to insert in a validation class and I'm trying to make it able to insert into the Visual Studio's Editor's IDE with all the context explained (if not enough just ask me) I want to the PropertyGrid to **show** its **EventsTab** like this in Visual Studio's IDE [image: EventsTab in PropertyGrid VS Editor]

But The problem is I have checked the [winforms sourcecode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#download,e4546bafe169f8fe,references) and for what I could understand I have found that in order to insert the Button for EventsTab we have to call `ShowEventsButton(true)` a private method of the PropertyGrid but that wont work (called it with reflection)

## So What I have tried so far...

- Caliing AddRefTab passing EventsTab with parameters (private method)
- Calling SetupToolbar with the true parameter (private method)
- Calling RefreshTabs
- Setting all TooltipItens to Visible
- Calling ShowEventsButton(true)

---

### Edit

I have two classes in this schem, one of them is the Validation class which inherits from the IValidation interface and it has the the events which I wanna show in the propertyGrid
the other class is a ControlValidator which derives from a component and has a list of Validation

### Edit 2

To be more specific what I'm trying to accomplish is to make use of the CollectionEditor (same window that is used to edit the collumns of a DataGridView) in this CollectionEditor I wanna make it show the EventsTab in its PropertyGrid (Actually I wanna make it be exactly like the PropertyTab of the VisualStudio IDE but I'm not in that part Yet) so the Events and property that I wanna show is of a List/Collection of the ControlValidator(component)

Let me try to make it more clear
[image: Class Diagram]
As you can see the Control Validator have a collection of the IValidation interface and it is the component so it should and is working like this
[image: ControlValidator working as it should be]
as you can see it does not show the events tab in the IDE because it does not have any events but if you double click the Validations property of the controlValidator it opens the CollectionEditor which have a PropertyGrid in there
[image: CollectionEditor]
And as a PropertyGrid I'm trying to make it show the eventsTab (which I'm not able to make it show in any of the ways I listed up there)

Comment: What do you want to show in the IDE - events from the Collection Items or the Validation Class?  In order for something to show in the IDE that way it would have to be a Control or Component.  So, is the Validator a Contol of some sort?

Comment: Your edits are making things more confusing.  A CollectionEditor is going to edit the `Items` which the Validator acts on.  A PropGrid can act on either the Validator Class or Collection Items.  So where are these events located, in the Validator or the Collection Items?  What is there to edit in a Runtime PropGrid Control regarding events?

Comment: The property grid you are showing is the `propertyBrowser` control for the standard collection editor.  It is farther away than you think: `CollectionEditor.CollectionForm.overArchingTableLayoutPanel.propertyBrowser`.  But there is **very** little it can do with events which is why it is doesnt show.  I'm pretty sure it will not be able to add events to your form for transient collection items.

Comment: @Plutonix it does not make much of a sense because when I Show its Type Full name it returns `System.Windows.Forms.Design.VsPropertyGrid` in which it appears to be only a default inheritance from PropertyGrid as seen in [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Design/System/Windows/Forms/Design/VsPropertyGrid.cs)

Comment: yes, it is a PropertyGrid. [see this](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/FX-1434/FX-1434/1@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Designer/CompMod/System/ComponentModel/Design/CollectionEditor@cs/1/CollectionEditor@cs) But **what** do you want the CollectionEditor to do with the event?  I dont think it can add event handlers to your form "like VS" for items if that is what you are after.  Consider the ListBox.  You do not get events from the items - you'd be forever adding/removing handlers.  Instead you get summary events from the control that something changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to provide a way for the events for a Custom class to show in the VS IDE Property Editor.

This can be done fairly simply with only a few changes to your class.  First, you need to understand that VS actually compiles your forms for use in the IDE designer.  Specifically, all that designer code in `InitializeComponent` needs to be compiled in order to create/draw your form.

This means in order to for your Class events (and props) to show in the IDE, your class needs to be a `Component` (or `Control`) so it can be compiled like any other for the IDE property editor.  It cant be a class you instance at runtime because that code is not examined for the form editor.

I've done this several times with classes that otherwise act as normal classes at runtime but with the added ability to set properties and so forth in the IDE via the from designer (a class with `ExtenderProvider` abilities, for example) .  The changes to your class start with something like this:

```
class Validator:Component, ISupportInitialize
{
    // fake props
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar  { get; set; }

    public event ValidatingEventHandler Validating;
    public delegate void ValidatingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event ValidatedEventHandler Validated;
    public delegate void ValidatedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public Validator(string foo, int bar) 
    { 
    }
    public Validator()
    {
    }

    // ISupportInitialize methods
    public void BeginInit()
    { 
    }
    public void EndInit()
    {
    }
}
```

Compile and the Validator will be available in the toolbox. Drag one to the form/Component tray.  Select it, open the Properties Editor *et voila* the properties and events show in the IDE:

[image]

Validator Component Properties ([click for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQeiJ.png)).  The Events View:

[image]

Double click the desired event and VS will add the skeleton event handler for you to edit.

### Care and Feeding of Components

Simply having your class inherit from Component does most of the work.  There are a few things related to Components which are required or may come up.  Most of these are simple issues and fixes.

#### Simple Ctor

As a Component, your Validator class will have to have a simple (parameterless) ctor.  VS has no idea how to instance it using the `(string foo, int bar)` version above.

This can cause problems if you have code which relies on those params to initialize other things in the constructor.  The answer for that is `ISupportIntialize`.

#### ISupportInitialize

This interface provides support for a BeginInit and EndInit method which VS will invoke from the designer code since it now takes care of setting your Component's properties:

```
// 
// validator1
// 
this.validator1.Bar = 0;
this.validator1.Foo = null;
this.validator1.Validating += new Validator.ValidatingEventHandler(this.validator1_Validating);
...
this.Text = "Form1";
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.validator1)).EndInit();
this.ResumeLayout(false);

...
private Validator validator1;          // note: no params
```

As you can see, one of the last things the designer code does, **after** all the properties have been set, is invoke `EndInit` on your class/Component.  Any initialization ctor code using `foo` or `bar` can be simply be moved to there.

#### Properties

The Properties as well as events for your class will now show in the IDE.  If you wish to hide any of these (perhaps it only has meaning when there are actual items to be validated), you can keep them from showing in the Property Pane using the `Browsable` attribute:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

In order to be certain that VS **does** serialize those you wish to be managed via the IDE, use the `DesignerSerialization` attribute:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
public int Bar  { get; set; }
```

Use `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden` for any property you do not wish VS to serialize.

Finally, the OP mentions a "collection of items" which the `Validator` works on.  If there is a collection class property on Validator (such as `Items`), the default collection editor will display for that property.  This may or may not be desirable depending on what the items are.  You can `[Browsable(false)]` on this to hide it.

If you **do** wish to add/edit items via the IDE, there is more work to do, but that is another kettle of fish.

---

#### Addendum

This is in regards to the new, emerging desire to access Item Events in the CollectionEditor and (apparently) have code created for them when clicked (created where, I am not sure).  There are a number of problems with this both as a design and in practice. I am assuming a structure like this:

```
Form.Validator.Items<ValidationItems>
```

First, the property grid used in the `CollectionEditor` is an internal one.  It is not hard to find on the `EditorForm`, but simply enabling the event view would not magically give it the power to know what to do when you click an event.  Since it is working with the collection, it knows little about the Type owning the collection, and less about the Form hosting the Type.

The events view is off in the CollectionEditor because it cant add event code to the form (the great-grandparent object of the Items!), because there is no form level object to reference.  It cant/wont add events to your collection class code because your code doesnt not have designer files.  Finally, the main requirement for a collection property is that the collection implement `IList`.  If your collection property is a plain List or Collection *variable*, there *is* no code file for it to modify.

To enable form events for the items it needs to be reconfigured. As an Item Class, they 'belong' to something else - the Validator class/component. If the Items are also reworked into a `Component`, form level events become possible:

```
[Serializable]
public class ValidationItem: Component
{
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(-1)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public event ValidatingEventHandler Validating;
    public delegate void ValidatingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public ValidationItem() 
    {
        Name = "New Item";
        Value = 0;
    }
}
```

Now, the Items will exist as a form component and be stored in the Validator's Items collection - similar to a DataGridView's columns.  To edit/add events, you still cannot do so from the CollectionEditor for the same reasons as before, but they are available from the IDE Properties Window.

Select the Item Component and use the Property Window as normal to add the event code to the designer and to the form (very much as with the `Validator` component in the original) :

```
//  (Designer)
// validationItem1
// 
this.validationItem1.DisplayName = "New Item";
this.validationItem1.Value = 0;
this.validationItem1.Validating += new ValidationItem.ValidatingEventHandler(this.validationItem1_Validating);

...
private ValidationItem validationItem1;     // persistent form var
```

in the form:

```
private void validationItem1_Validating(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

As a component, all the earlier points about them now applies to the items as well.

#### The Drawbacks

a) If there are a lot of Items, there will be a lot of `ValidationItems` in the Component Tray.  The first thing I would ask myself is whether I need the Validator Class *and* all these items as individual form level objects.

b) As with controls, if you remove one, it will remove code from the designer, but not the form. Duplicate code can result as you change/update your items (collection contents tend to be more volatile):

```
private void validationItem1_Validating(object sender, EventArgs e)
...
private void validationItem1_Validating_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
...
private void validationItem1_Validating_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

---

This approach seems "noisy" to me.  The CollectionClass is perfectly capable of hooking up to the Items' events which are then bubbled up to the form in the form of one single `Validator` event.  Why have 15 or even 5 events to maintain when one may work? Shouldn't consolidating all that be part of the job of the `Validator` class?  Ex:

```
private void validator1_ValidationComplete(object sender, 
                     ValidationCompleteEventArgs e) 
{
}
```

`ValidationCompleteEventArgs` could report which item did or did not validate, when, why, provide a `CancelRemaining` capability or whatever the form needs to know.  This of is not unlike a `ListBox` or `DataGridView` which reports events on behalf of the stuff it contains.

Comment: Not quite like that I dont want it to show on the VisualStudio's Property Window but in the PropertyGrid Control the Image of the PropertyWindow of visualstudio is only for reference of the Events Button

Comment: That's is not what you said in the now deleted reply to my question above.

Comment: Sorry for that I wrote and after that I realized that I misplaced things but the place where I'm now have a bad internet connection so I delayed some time to delete the comment @Plutonix

Comment: You sir, is the Real MVP, the Validator(ControlValidor) is not the one to handle the validations because in some controls I would like to have multiple validations with multiples Feedbacks to the user, in the way I wrote my validation class It handles itself to give the user a feedback, so the ControlValidor would be like an Collection of Validations and shoudl have methods like isEveryValidationValidated so I could check before I save something or other stuff